# read and write variables in the PLC (beckhoff CX9020) with python pyads module

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ads, virtual, plc

I would like realize a communication gateway, with the ADS protocol between a virtual machine (VM) under lunix (Debian9) and the PLC (Beckhoff CX9020), using the python pyads module.
I created the route by following the link below
https://pyads.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html
Here is my code:

```
import pyads

print ("=== set_local_address");
pyads.open_port ()
pyads.set_local_address ('1.2.3.4.1.1')
print (pyads.get_local_address ())
pyads.close_port ()

print ("=== add route");
pyads.open_port ()
pyads.add_route ('5.82.237.216.1.1', '192.168.0.20')
pyads.close_port ()

print ("=== add route to plc");
SENDER_AMS = '1.2.3.4.1.1'
PLC_IP = '192.168.0.20'
PLC_USERNAME = 'Administrator'
PLC_PASSWORD = 'x'
ROUTE_NAME = 'RouteToMyPC'
HOSTNAME = '192.168.0.15' # or IP
PLC_AMS_ID = '5.82.237.216.1.1'
pyads.add_route_to_plc (SENDER_AMS, HOSTNAME, PLC_IP, PLC_USERNAME, PLC_PASSWORD, route_name = ROUTE_NAME)

print ("=== init connection to plc");
plc = pyads.Connection (PLC_AMS_ID, 851, PLC_IP)

print ("=== open connection")
plc.open ()
print ('Connected')
v1 = plc.read_by_name ("MAIN.v1", pyads.PLCTYPE_INT)
print (v1)
```

I can access to the PLC, but I cannot read or write, I still get the error message

---

```
Connecting... 
2021-01-21117:17:59+0100 Info: Connected to 192.168.0.20 
Connected 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "rw_pyads.py", tine 34, in <module> 
      value = plc.read by_name('MAIN.vr, pyads.PLCTYPE INT) 
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyads/ads.py", line 761, in read_by_name 
      return adsSyncReadByNameEx( 
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyads/pyads_ex.py", line 977, in adsSyncReadByNameEx
      handle = adsGetHandle(port, address, data name) 
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyads/pyads_ex.py", line 770, in adsGetHandle
      handle = adsSyncReadWriteReqEx2(
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyads/pyads_ex.py", line 638, in adsSyncReadWriteReqEx2
      raise ADSError(err code)
pyads.pyads ex.ADSError: ADSError: timeout elapsed (1861). 
2021-01-21117:18:04+0100 Info: connection closed by remote
```

---

Has anyone ever encountered this problem ?
Can someone explain me what is the exact problem?
I spent days, but failed to resolve the issues
Thank you !

Comment: Considering the timeout error my first guess would be the host can't be reached at all. Are you sure you got the right IP? Can the VM reach the Machine at all, i.e. did you set the right virtual ethernet adapter?

Comment: hi did you mange to find a solution, i am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, had a python script sharing variables with Twincat3 however after 20min the connection drop to close connection.

Manage to "solve" by restarting the connection the batch file, after the error. So now everytime the error appears the connection is restored.

Good luck!
Gonçalo

Comment: hi,
 i am having the same issue, can you please elaborate on what you mean by restarting the connection ?